# How to display mysql table record with join 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, `tb_injectiontemp`, `tb_injection`, and `tb_notify_esim` respectively.

these are records of `tb_injectiontemp`:

| knackid | status | post_date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 331293 | 1 | 2023-06-06 10:30:10 |
| 331293 | 1 | 2023-06-06 10:43:13 |
| 331293 | 1 | 2023-06-06 10:59:55 |
| 331293 | 1 | 2023-06-06 12:06:35 |

and these are records of `tb_injection` :

| tanggal | knackid | status_injection | idinject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-06 10:33:03 | 331293 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-06-06 10:45:04 | 331293 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-06-06 11:04:04 | 331293 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-06-06 12:07:03 | 331293 | 1 | 2686028024114530 |

and this is the record of `tb_notify_esim` :

| idinject | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2686028024114530 | 2023-06-06 12:07:21 |

Can you give me a query to get result records like this?

| knackid | post_date2 | idinject | tanggal | status_injection | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 331293 | 2023-06-06 12:06:35 | 2686028024114530 | 2023-06-06 12:07:03 | 1 | 2023-06-06 12:07:21 |
| 331293 | 2023-06-06 10:59:55 | 0 | 2023-06-06 11:04:04 | 2 | NULL |
| 331293 | 2023-06-06 10:43:13 | 0 | 2023-06-06 10:45:04 | 2 | NULL |
| 331293 | 2023-06-06 10:30:10 | 0 | 2023-06-06 10:33:03 | 2 | NULL |

this is my query, but it still didn't work.

```
SELECT
  tb_injectiontemp.knackid,
  tb_injectiontemp.post_date2,
  tb_injection.idinject,
  tb_injection.tanggal,
  tb_injection.status as status_injection,
  tb_notify_esim.created_at
FROM
  tb_injectiontemp
JOIN
  tb_injection ON
    tb_injectiontemp.knackid = tb_injection.knackid
LEFT JOIN
  tb_notify_esim ON
    tb_injection.idinject = tb_notify_esim.idinject
WHERE tb_injection.knackid = 331293
GROUP BY tb_injection.tanggal 
ORDER BY
  tb_injection.tanggal DESC;
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"it still didn't work"_ is not a problem description. Describe what happened and include the complete text of any error messages you see.

Comment: *these are records of* Provide the data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. *Can you give me a query to get result records like this?* Needed output must match the sample data completely, not "like this". See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Typo on your query tb_injection.status , change it to tb_injection.status_injection

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Xun, but I still cant show column post_date2 according to data in tb_injectiontemp

Answer (score 0):

This will work.You had a typo in tb_injection.status  it should be tb_injection.status .

```
 SELECT
      tb_injectiontemp.knackid,
      tb_injectiontemp.post_date2,
      tb_injection.idinject,
      tb_injection.tanggal,
      tb_injection.status_injection as status_injection,
      tb_notify_esim.created_at
    FROM
      tb_injectiontemp
    JOIN
      tb_injection  ON
        tb_injectiontemp.knackid = tb_injection.knackid
    LEFT JOIN
      tb_notify_esim ON
        tb_injection.idinject = tb_notify_esim.idinject
    WHERE tb_injection.knackid = 331293
    GROUP BY tb_injection.tanggal 
    ORDER BY
      tb_injection.tanggal DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in column post_date2 all record still display 10:30:10